# Yii Relational Queries with MySQL's SUM

Tags: php, mysql, yii

In Yii 1.1.x using relational queries, consider the following tables:

Table 'Invoice'

```
id, original_balance, invoice_date, due_date
```

Table 'InvoicePayments'

```
id, invoice_id, payment_amount, old_balance, new_balance, payment_date
```

Modal `invoice.php` `function relations()`:

```
'Payments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'InvoicePayments', array( 'id' => 'invoice_id' )
```

If I want to use a relational query on a particular `Invoice` object, how can I get the `SUM` of all `InvoicePayments.payment_amount`?

Example (doesn't work):

`$model = Invoice::model()->with( array( 'InvoicePayments' => array( "??.SUM(payment_amount) )->findByPk(1);`

I am finding that without this I have to pull the relational query without the `SUM` and loop through each `InvoicePayments.payment_amount` to get the total amount paid towards the invoice.

Any help is appreciated, thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Statistical Query *STAT*](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query) provided by **Active Record** and force it to use the [SQL SUM function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) by assigning  its **select** option :

*invoice.php :*

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'payments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'InvoicePayments', array( 'id' => 'invoice_id' )
        'paymentsSum'=>array(self::STAT, 'InvoicePayments', 'invoice_id', 'select' => 'SUM(payment_amount)'),
    );
}
```

Then you can use it to load one or many models by using any of the *lazy* or *eager* approache, here is 3 different examples :

```
// the lazy loading approach
$invoice=Invoice::model()->findByPk(10);
$total = $invoice->paymentsSum;

// the eager loading approach
$invoices=Invoice::model()->with('paymentsSum')->findByPk(10);
$total = $invoice->paymentsSum;

// the eager loading approach to load all invoices
$invoices=Invoice::model()->with('paymentsSum')->findAll();
$total_of_invoice_10 = $invoices[10]->paymentsSum;
```